# Tkinter: Putting Code Into Class Breaks Python

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I have this really simple and short few lines of code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

w = tk.Canvas(master, width=800, height=600)
w.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

master.mainloop()
```

For readibility, extended functionality, portability and other reasons I want to put the code into a class, like this:

```
class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.create_window()
    def create_window(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=800, height=600)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Example()
    app.mainloop()
```

The code runs fine, exactly like the one above, but when I stop the program I get a "Python has stopped working" message. It doesn't affect the program itself but I want to know what's causing it and why it runs perfectly outside a class.

Comment: What do you mean stop it?

Comment: how do you run this code ? directly in terminal/console/cmd.exe or in IDE/IDLE ?

Comment: When I click the X or stop it from the cmd.exe.

Comment: I can say: code is OK. I don't know why you get this message (but I don't use Windows and I can't test this problem) but I wouldn't bother this

Comment: I don't want to see an error message for no apparent reason everytime I close the program.

Comment: On my machine, this runs fine and doesn't crash on closing.

Comment: I add `self.canvas.create_rectangle(100,100,120,120)` to check canvas :) and I'm sure it shows canvas on my computer - Linux Mint.

Comment: Try not to subclass `tk.Tk`, or subclass `tk.Frame` instead

Comment: @user1234259 Runs fine for me from IDLE or cmd.exe in Windows 7. Could this be an installation problem?

Comment: I ran the code provided and no error message is received. What OS are you using? I tested on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter's Tk and other classes have hundreds of methods and attributes. I know that if one read ancient GUI programing books, from the times of Windows 3.x, the recommendation for creating your own Windows would be to subclass the underlying library widget and wrtite yoru code. That is what you are trying to do above, by subclassing Tk.

Well, **do not do that**. Really, don't. That way you can't create any attribute on your class without triple-checking if it is not colliding with some other attribute.

Use inhretance in OO to create your own class hierarchy - and that is a relevant and ordered thing that will make things easier to you. To inherit from the GUI code' Window, and attach members to it like "name_text_entry" and "name_variable" (and repeat that for each input control in your program)  is a thing that is easily perceived as mixing very different things (Window control attributes and methods) with the internal workings of your own program. [Here is a more extensive consideration](http://blog.berniesumption.com/software/inheritance-is-evil-and-must-be-destroyed/) on why this pattern does not work (not in Python, but I just picked it from the first Google results)

So, just create your own program, and leave Tkinter's classes alone - unless you are creating a new custom Widget (to be used in another part of the code).

Your code should be more like:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.tk = tk.Tk(*args, **kw)
        self.create_window()

    def create_window(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=800, height=600)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

And just work.
The error message, as seen in the comments, is not deterministic, and can be yielded by lots of different factors - from tkinter.Tk internally depending on not being subclassed (even if that is a bug), to it having an internal "canvas" attribute, and so on.

Just use composition and be happy.